# Changing an OpenSSL BIO from blocking to non-blocking mode

Tags: c, openssl

I have a multithreaded application that makes heavy use of OpenSSL in C. It is designed with the idea that all of its SSL connections are expected to block. Specifically, blocking BIOs. They are all allocated off a single incoming port like this:

```
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
sock = BIO_new_socket(socket, BIO_CLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, sock, sock);
```

As it turns out though, there are a few small parts of the codebase where using non-blocking BIOs would be the best choice. The small parts that would benefit from the non-blocking BIOs have no way of knowing which SSL connections will belong to them. Thus, they always receive blocking BIOs.

The question is, can the blocking BIOs be changed to be non-blocking?

I know that [BIO_set_nbio](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_connect.html) can be used to make a BIO non-blocking but the documentation says:

> The call to BIO_set_nbio() should be made before the connection is established because non blocking I/O is set during the connect process.

Another possible option I have thought about would be to copy the BIO and recreate it, while somehow maintaining all of the state.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are having. It's reasonable that non-blocking IO is set up when the connection is established and surely you can abstract your code in a way that handles that.

Comment: The problem is it is a _large_ change to make the IO non-blocking when the connection is established.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did non-blocking SSL connections in my own "lion" code, but I did not use the BIO functionality in OpenSSL at all.

Rather, I went for the calls
`SSL_set_fd(ctx, fd )` and `SSL_get_fd(ssl)` to handle my own fdsets and calling `select`.

The biggest 'gotcha' that took a while to track down was to set `SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER` and `SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE` for it work the way I wanted.

If you want to read the SSL part of the code, it is here:

https://github.com/lundman/lion/blob/master/src/tls.c